# How do I pull a guard off a roof in Assassin's Creed 2?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2

Every time I try to assassinate a guard on a roof, I always jump up and kill him with my hidden blade.  How do I pull a guard off a roof to assassinate him in Assassin's Creed 2?

Comment: Note that the pull guard off move is done without high profile on (right mouse button). Just assassinate with attack key when you have focus and are close enough. You also need that skill before you can use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hang from the ledge, lock onto the guard, and wait for him to be right next to you.When guard near to you, the top right corner of screen says 'assassinate'. Then press the 'left click' button and it will perform the kill and pull him off. You have to have gotten the codex page to unlock this assassination technique in order to perform.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about roofs, but if you're next to water, you can stay hanging on the ledge underneath the guard and press the main hand button (click on pc's) and Ezio will punch the guard with his hidden blade, grab him and throw him overboard.

Answer (score -1):

Don't have your blade weapon selected.  To pull him off, you need to have no weapons selected (fist) and wait until you see the button to assassinate.  I too prefer to pull'em off.  Takes the fun out of it if they're dead before they hit the ground, doesn't it?

Comment: This is incorrect, using the hidden blade and low-profile you can "assassinate" guards above you - Ezio will reach up, stab the guard and drag them off the roof using the blade. Unlike throwing them, where they might land on a low roof or something and potentially survive, this *will* kill them.